# How to prevent style if parent has a specific class

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of CSS that's used in my application. Unfortunately I need this bit of CSS to not apply if parent in the hierarchy has a specific class `disableSpecialCSS`

```
 *,
 *::before,
 *::after {
   border-width: 3px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: red;
 }
```

Example DOM structure

```
<div class="disableSpecialCSS" contenteditable="true">    
    <p><br></p>
</div>
```

Based on this html structure, div1, div2, span1, span2 **shouldn't** have the css applied because parent div has class **disableSpecialCSS**

I tried the following but it only prevent css to apply where it's not that css instead of all the children

```
body *:not(.disableSpecialCSS),
body *:not(.disableSpecialCSS)::before,
body *:not(.disableSpecialCSS)::after {
   border-width: 3px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: red;
 }
```

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```css
body :not(.disableSpecialCSS) *,
body :not(.disableSpecialCSS) *::before,
body :not(.disableSpecialCSS) *::after {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="disableSpecialCSS" contenteditable="true">    
        <p><br></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `*` selector inside the `:not` selector.

```css
body :not(.disableSpecialCSS) *,
body :not(.disableSpecialCSS) *::before,
body :not(.disableSpecialCSS) *::after {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p><br></p>
  </div>
  <div class="disableSpecialCSS" contenteditable="true">
    <p><br></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Perhaps a more solid solution would be this.

```css
body :not(.reset, .reset *),
body :not(.reset, .reset *)::after,
body :not(.reset, .reset *)::before {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p><br></p>
<section>
  <div class="reset" contenteditable="true">
    <p><br></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately your bit of CSS does not work with my html structure posted. It should be any parent, not necessarily immediate parent.

Comment: immediate ancestor is written with `parent > child` but it's not used, so anything inside that class will get styles removed.

Comment: I have added your new code snippet to my answer, you see it works. Make sure you have the code in an actual body element, as this is what your rule does.

Comment: Hi There. One more tiny question. May I ask do you know how I tweak it such that the css will apply in anywhere in the dom. Atm it only works if it's directly inbetween the body

Comment: I have added another way, it's probably more solid.